# Search a file by a word and then print specific number of line in C++

Tags: c++

I'm just a beginner, trying to save 3 different student records in a file and then reading the records using the student names. I want information regarding the name like name, roll number and marks. This is the code so far but it displays the whole file.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct student
{
  string name;
  int rollno;
  float marks;
};
main()
{
  student s1,s2,s3;
  int search;
  string line;
  cout<<"Enter Name: ";
  getline(cin,s1.name);
  cout<<"Enter Roll No: ";
  cin>>s1.rollno;
  cout<<"Enter Marks: ";
  cin>>s1.marks;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Enter Name: ";
  getline(cin,s2.name);
  getline(cin,s2.name);
  cout<<"Enter Roll No: ";
  cin>>s2.rollno;
  cout<<"Enter Marks: ";
  cin>>s2.marks;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"Enter Name: ";
  getline(cin,s3.name);
  getline(cin,s3.name);
  cout<<"Enter Roll No: ";
  cin>>s3.rollno;
  cout<<"Enter Marks: ";
  cin>>s3.marks;
  cout<<endl;
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("Record.txt");
  fout<<"Name: "<<s1.name<<endl;
  fout<<"Roll No: "<<s1.rollno<<endl;
  fout<<"Marks: "<<s1.marks<<endl;
  fout<<"Name: "<<s2.name<<endl;
  fout<<"Roll No: "<<s2.rollno<<endl;
  fout<<"Marks: "<<s2.marks<<endl;
  fout<<"Name: "<<s3.name<<endl;
  fout<<"Roll No: "<<s3.rollno<<endl;
  fout<<"Marks: "<<s3.marks<<endl;
  fout.close();
  cout<<"Search By Name: ";
  cin>>search;
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("Record.txt");
  while(getline(fin,line))
  {
     if(line.find(search))
     {
        cout<<line<<endl;
     }
     else
     {
        cout<<"Record Not Found!";
     }
  }
  fin.close();
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code? Does  it not do what you want it to do? Please explain how

Comment: Not directly related, but your text file will contain 3 lines per student record. Is is really what you want?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 it prints the full file, I just want it to print the record of only 1 student

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes and then I want to search using the name and get all 3 records of that name which will be name, roll no and marks and every other line should not be displayed

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
if(line.find(search))
```

appears to assume `std::string::find` would return something that converts to `true` in case the search string was found and `false` otherwise.

If you read up what it actually does (eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)) you will find that its return value is:

> Position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no such substring is found.

Hence the only case the condition of the above `if` evaluates to `false` is when the position of the substring is `0` (ie it was actually found). You can try to see this in action if you write the name of the student in the beginning of the line. With your current code, only that line will be skipped. What you really want is

```
if (line.find(search) != std::string::npos)
```

Next, you mistakenly declared `search` as an `int`. You probably did not get an error, because there is an overload of `find` that takes a `char`. I would have expected at least a warning for that. Anyhow, `search` should be a `std::string`.

Once you have that fixed, you do not want to print `""Record Not Found!"` for every single line that does not contain the name you are looking for. Perhaps use a `bool` flag that tells you if you already found the line.

Also, you have to adjust your code to print also the next two lines when you found the correct entry.

```
bool found = false;
while(getline(fin,line)) {
    if(line.find(search) != std::string::npos) {
        found = true;
        cout << line << endl; 
        // todo: read and print also the next two lines         
        break; // leave the while loop
    }
}
if (found == false) cout<<"Record Not Found!";
```

The `break` is to stop reading the file once you found the correct entry. When there could be more students with the same name you might want to remove it.

Last not least you should reconsider your logic. What if a students name is "Roll" or "Marks" ? Unlikely, but you can prevent your code from failing in such case if you request the line you are looking for to be `"Name: [name of student]"` instead of only requiring to contain the students name somewhere.

Comment: Thanks!!! but now I'm stuck at how to print the next line ugh

Comment: @Umair I didnt post the whole solution so you can still have some fun with it :P. Just use `getline` again

Comment: yesss i figured it out but forgot to edit my comment lol thanks a lot tho!